# I want to update every 3 seconds without using react apollo refetch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo

I am using react apollo.
I want to update the user.percent of the progressbar component every 3 seconds without using apllo's refetch.

```
import {useInterval} from 'beautiful-react-hooks';

const ProgressBar = () => {
  const {userId} = useParams<{userId: string}>();
  const {data: {user = null} = {}, refetch: refetchUser} =
    useUserQuery({
      variables: {uuid: userId},
      skip: !userId,
    });
  if (!user) return null;

  useInterval(() => {
    refetchUser();
  }, 3000);

  return (
     <p>{user.percent}</p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Apollo's polling feature](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#polling) to execute query evey X millisecond.

```
  const {data: {user = null} = {}, startPolling, stopPolling} = useUserQuery({
      variables: {uuid: userId},
      skip: !userId,
      pollInterval: 3000, // <-- refetch every 3 sec

    });
```

You can start and pause/stop polling using `startPolling` and `stopPolling` functions respectively.

Comment: How can I use startPolling and stopPolling?

Comment: Like a regular function? You need to explain what you mean by that very very generic question. Also, your original question just demands another way to make repeated calls which this answer answers.

Comment: If you think this answer helped you, please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I see your profile, and you do not seem to accept or upvote answers, this will discourage users to answer your questions in the future.